# Pass ArrayList<String> from fragment to another fragment

Tags: android-fragments, arraylist, fragment, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

I have a problem. I'm building an Android app. I created a Tabbed Activity with Android Studio. I have 3 tabs. I created 3 classes java with their relative xml. In first tab I take data from internet with Jsoup and i put these data in 2 ArrayList. I want to pass these ArrayList to tab2 and tab3 to avoid downloading again these data.

How can i do? I tried with bundle and getter/setter but I have not been successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to be make that `ArrayList` as static one. Once you got the required data in `fragment A` then assign that data into `ArrayList`. Now you can easily access from anywhere.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately your solution non working. I make ArrayList static in MainActivity but not pass the date. Then I tried to put static ArrayList in first fragment but don't work

Comment: can you please tell me how you make ArrayList as static and how you accessed in the fragment?

Comment: In main Activity I put

`cpublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

   public static ArrayList<String> people10 = new ArrayList<String>();
   ....
   ....


 public void setList(ArrayList<String> people10)
     {
         this.people10 = people10;
     }
     public ArrayList<String> getList ()
     {
         return people10;
     }


}`


Then in first fragment i put

`    public static ArrayList<String> people10 = new ArrayList<String>();

     .....
     setList(list);


`

In second fragment i want to get people10 ArrayList<String>

Comment: No need to write setters and getters for the ***people10 ArrayList<String>*. Just assign the values what you are getting from server like **people10 = list**. and call this in Fragment b like **FragmentA.people10**

Comment: Works :) Thank you very much :)